# What should I know when I define a bash function to use a program's name?

Tags: bash

In many cases I need to create functions with the same name as other programs, and I've no idea if it is a good way to use bash scripting.

Example:

```
    function echo () {
        echo -n "$@" ;
    }
```

After testing it looks like it checks functions names inside script before bin paths.
I want to make sure about that and any other info I should know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo() {
  command echo -n "$@"
}
```

Using `command` here means asking for the `echo` command (which happens to be builtin here) instead of the function one which otherwise would take precedence.

And since here, `echo` also happens to be a builtin (is not looked-up in `$PATH` BTW as builtins have precedence over filesystem commands), you could also do:

```
echo() {
  builtin echo -n "$@"
}
```

That latter approach is preferable in `zsh`, where `command echo` would run `/bin/echo` instead (except in `sh` emulation).

There are some subtle variations between shells, but the order of precedence is generally:

1. special builtins
2. functions
3. builtins
4. commands in `$PATH` (and the order depends on the order in `$PATH` and in the `hash` table as managed by the `hash` builtin)

Bearing in mind that aliases and keywords in the shell syntax (`for`, `if`...), when not quoted are considered before those.

The order of `1` and `2` is reversed in some shells like `bash` or `zsh`. `bash` doesn't allow functions to be defined with the same name as a special builtin when invoked as `sh`.